# AngularStrap datepicker shows wrong date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-strap

I've met the following problem with angularStrap datepicker:
if I set via controller any date of 2014 year, then the displayed value will be the same but of 2013 year.

For example: if I set `2014-10-12` value in controller, then the displayed value will be `2013-10-12`

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select Date" ng-model="updated_at" bs-datepicker data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" data-date-type="string" data-autoclose="1">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap'])
    .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.updated_at = '2014-10-12';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexeime/83b747pw/

http://take.ms/Cjk4S

There are no such problems with dates of other years.

**EDIT**:

There is no problem in IE11 & Firefox, but the problem exists in Google Chrome 38.0.2125.101 m (Windows 7 64-bit)

Comment: Tried your JSFiddle with same Chrome version and Win8, and it works fine.

Comment: Hmmm, I met the same problem on my another computer with Win8. The problem remains even if I turn off all extensions